# unable to build C++ project in Eclipse helios

Tags: c++

I can't build a C++ project in eclipse helios. It's showing an error (Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)

I saw a suggestion that stated  add PATH to (Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment).
But the variable name is PATH, what do I give in the value?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you install MinGW? You'll need to put the MinGW bin directory in your path.

Or you can use Cygwin.